# How do I remove "^M" from a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, osx

I have two "identical" files that I compare in diff, and it shows that every line is different, after looking at the file I found that one of them has `^M` at the end of every line. How do I remove this? I tried this `sed` command:

```
sed -i '' -E 's/^M//g'
```

this `tr` command: (which even if it worked I wouldn't want since I want to do in place editing)

```
tr -d '^M'
```

and this `perl` command:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^M//g'
```

But none of those changed the contents.

Comment: Make sure you are using `ctrl-V, ctrl-M`, not simply typing `^M`.

Comment: @DavidBetz typing literally ctrl + M just makes a new line in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I've found these functions in [kenrob's .vimrc](https://github.com/kenorb/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) in his [dotfiles repository](https://github.com/kenorb/dotfiles):

```
" Removes the ^M character from the end of every line
function! RemoveM()
    :%s/^M$//ge
endfunction

" Replaces the ^M character with a carraige return native to the system
function! ReplaceM()
    :%s/^M/\r/ge
endfunction
```

So you can easily adopt these functions and use Vim to deal with those `^M` characters.